# memcpy: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer

Tags: c, file, memcpy

I use the read() function to read in 40 characters from a file, and need to copy from the offset of 10 for the length of 20. In other words, I need to do memcpy from the 10th to 30th characters into a new memory address. When I run my code (see following), however, I got the warning message: `warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer`

```
int main()
{
    void *buffer = malloc(40);
    int fd = open("example20.txt", O_RDONLY);
    printf("the value of fd is %d \n", fd);


/* read 40 characters from the file */ 
int bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, 40);

void *new_container = malloc(20);

/* copy from buffer, starting offset at 10 for length of 20 */
memcpy(new_container, &buffer[10], 20);
printf("new_container is %s \n", (char *) new_container);

return 0;
}
```

I am wondering what this error means, and how to fix it?

edit1: I found a way of solving the problem: by casting the buffer from void* to a new char* pointer.

```
char *buffer2 = (char *) buffer;
memcpy(new_container, &buffer2[10], 20);
```

edit2: I found a way of using void* pointer in memcpy: `memcpy(new_container, buffer+10, 20)`; the variable "buffer" in this way can be a void* type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the line

```
memcpy(new_container, &buffer[10], 20);
```

to

```
memcpy(new_container, (char *)buffer + 10, 20);
```

That's because `&buffer[10]` evaluates to`&(*(buffer + 10))` because the array subscript operator has higher precedence than the `address of` operator `&`. However, `buffer` is of type `void *` and pointer arithmetic cannot be done on `void` pointers because there is no size information. Using the typecast operator `(char *)` on `buffer` provides the necessary size information so that 
`(char *)buffer + 10` is equivalent to `buffer + 10 * sizeof(char)` or the address of the `11`th  element in the buffer pointed to by the variable `buffer`.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is due to this:

```
&buffer[10]
```

`void` has no size, and the `[]` operator needs a concrete data type to operate in a defined manner. That this is a warning is probably due to your compiler supporting `void*` in an `unsigned char *` manner (gcc has this extension, for example). But it isn't standard. Thus the warning.

Change this:

```
void *buffer = malloc(40);
```

To this:

```
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(40);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick replies. The reason why I needed "buffer" to be a void pointer is my program cannot assume reading strings/characters, sometimes, it could be an mp3 file or other format. I wonder if I can still make "buffer" a char type?

Comment: @TonyGW you should have no problem using `unsigned char *` for that effort (and you'll likely find it easier to use/debug in the long run).

Comment: I found a way of using void* pointer in memcpy: memcpy(new_container, buffer+10, 20); the variable "buffer" in this way can be a void* type

Comment: @TonyGW You may skip the warning (and I'm shocked if it does), but the validity of the statement is still supported by extension only. `buffer+10` where `buffer` is `void*` has *no concrete type* on which to perform the pointer arithmetic. `gcc` will do it, but it is **not** standard. To be standard-compliant, you either need to use a typed-pointer, or cast to a typed-pointer type *before* the arithmetic (see ajay's answer for such a cast, this answer for just using a typed-pointer).

Answer (score 3):

The error/warning is for line

```
memcpy(new_container, &buffer[10], 20);
```

Here you are trying to access 11th element of `buffer`. But as `buffer` is `void *`, doing `buffer[10]` is not valid.

You need to define it as

```
char *buffer = malloc(40);
```

Similarly for `new_container`.

Comment: `char *buffer = (char*)malloc(40);`

Comment: @Lashane: No, Rohan's version is correct, yours is redundant and allows for a subtle error if you forgot to include `stdlib.h` on compilers which allow implicit int. This is C, not C++. There exists an implicit conversion from `void*` to any other type of pointer. No one who actually knows C casts the return value of `malloc`.