# Towards understanding void pointers

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, void

In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234805/2411320) I mention that dereferencing a `void` pointer is a bad idea. However, what happens when I do this?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void) {
 void* c = malloc(4);
 *c;
 &c[0];
}
```

Compilation:

```
gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:4:2: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
  *c;
  ^~
prog.c:5:4: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
  &c[0];
    ^
prog.c:5:2: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
  &c[0];
  ^
```

Here is an image from Wandbox for those who say it didn't happen:

[image]

and a <kbd>Live demo</kbd> in Ideone.

It will actually try to read what the memory that `c` points to has, and then fetch that result, but actually do nothing in the end? Or this line will simply have no effect (but then GCC wouldn't produce a warning).

I am thinking that since the compiler doesn't know anything about the data type, it won't be able to do much, without knowing the size of the type.

Why derefencing a `void*` does not produce an error, but just a warning?

---

If I try an assignment, I will get an error:

> invalid use of void expression

but shouldn't the dereferencing alone produce an error?

Comment: Since `void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed, dereferencing a `void *` should generate a compiler diagnostic.

Comment: some compilers assume 1 for size of void when pointed on (at least with pointer arithmetic)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes that's what I am saying, I would expect an error to occur. Jean, let's focus on GCC.

Comment: I think it is a GNU extension. Well, at least the [`void` pointer arithmetic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith)

Comment: maybe related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113301/how-void-pointer-arithmetic-is-happening-in-gcc

Comment: I'd also be interested in how a compiler treats `&c[0];`

Comment: umm..not really, with `-std=c99 -pedantic`, only warning, not error.

Comment: If that is a (non-compliant) gcc extension, you chould use that tag. `memory` is pointless. Sure this compiles with gcc? IIRC, it only allows arithmetics, but not dereferencing. With warnings enabled you should get an "unused value" (or so) message. Try an assignment.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I compile in Wandbox.org, with GCC and G11 (not the GNU extension). Olaf, that's what I am asking, an assigment will trigger an error to be generated, but my code doesn't!

Comment: @gsamaras: Once more: Enable **all** recommended warnings. There is definitively one which will warn about such empty statements (you can circumvent them by casting to `void`, but that is fine)..

Comment: Due the nature of the question your [mcve] should include complete compilation command and compiler message output.

Comment: This question is not about understanding void pointers, it's about understanding [a GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html), which does not help understand anything about what the C standard says about `void*` (if anything it probably confuses things and makes you understand less).

Comment: @SouravGhosh, _"with `-std=c99 -pedantic`, only warning, not error"_ yes, that's because `-pedantic` causes warnings (which are still diagnostics!), not errors. Use `pedantic-errors` to get errors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler-- are you sure that dereferencing a pointer to `void` must generate a compiler diagnostic? [§6.5.3.2/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p2) only says: "The operand of the unary * operator shall have pointer type." Doesn't `(void *)` qualify, even though it is incomplete?

Comment: @DavidBowling "shall have a pointer type" doesn't mean all pointer types are valid ("dereference → ptr" != "ptr → dereferencable")

Comment: @Kevin-- I didn't say that it is valid to dereference a `void` pointer. It doesn't look to me like the Standard requires a _diagnostic message_ if an attempt to dereference a `void` pointer is made. The passage I cited is a constraint, and constraint violations must trigger diagnostic messages....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From C11 6.3.2.3 "void":

> The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has type void) shall not be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be applied to such an expression.  If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its side effects.)

So an expression can have void type, you just can't do anything with the result of that expression (such as assign it to something). `*c` is a valid expression that does nothing.

6.2.5/19 "Types"

> The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed.

6.5.6/2 "Additive operators"

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other shall have integer type.

And array subscripting is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic. So normally, the expression `&c[0]` would not be allowed.

GCC allows pointer arithmetic on (and therefore subscripting arrays of) void types as an extension.

Answer (score 12):

The C standard explicitly states in [5.1.1.3p1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.3):

> A conforming implementation shall produce **at least one diagnostic message** (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances. 9)

With footnote 9 saying that

> The intent is that an implementation should identify the nature of, and where possible localize, each violation. Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated. **It may also successfully translate an invalid program.**

So, GCC complies with the letter of the C standard. Your program is an invalid program. Only a diagnostics message is required - and the compiler is allowed to successfully translate your invalid program. As GCC has a *non-standard* extension for [void pointer arithmetic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html):

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to `void` and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a `void` or of a function as `1`.
>
> A consequence of this is that `sizeof` is also allowed on `void` and on function types, and returns `1`.
>
> The option `-Wpointer-arith` requests a warning if these extensions are used.

it decided that it might do something "sensible" with your invalid program and translated it successfully.

---

Notice that non-evaluated dereference of *pointer-to-void* is already required in `sizeof`, because:

```
void *foo;
sizeof *foo;
```

must match that of

```
sizeof (void);
```

They both evaluate to 1, so it is just easier allow the discarded dereference of pointers to void *everywhere*.

---

As Lundin says, if you want actual errors for constraint violations, use **`-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`**.

Comment: The OP is not properly compiling as standard C, in which case you get an error about void pointer used in arithmetic. As I understand it, the question is about non-standard GCC only.

Comment: Compiling properly with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors` gives: `warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer|
error: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]|
warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer|
warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]|`. The OP does not compile like this so what the standard says doesn't apply.

Comment: @Lundin a compliant compiler is allowed to successfully compile the code. It just is required that diagnostics is produced. Therefore `-pedantic` will be enough to achieve compliance.

Comment: @Lundin I am asking for Standard C! I compiled in Wandbox with `$ gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` and got the warning only.

Comment: @Lundin as this answer clearly says, only **a diagnostic message** is required, so a warning is standards conforming.

Comment: Yes I know. That's my point, the OP **did not get a diagnostic message for invalid pointer arithmetic**.

Comment: @gsamaras your question doesn't mention `-pedantic-errors`. If that doesn't lead to an error, I'd report a bug against GCC...

Comment: It does give an error for one line: `prog.c:5:4: error: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]`

Comment: @Lundin, a warning is a diagnostic message

Comment: Yes because I didn't use. I saw @Lundin's comment and tried it out. I compiled with a simpler attempt `gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`, but yet failed to get an error...A bug you say?

Comment: @gsamaras link or it didn't happen. Your original code gives a pedantic error. Dereferencing the pointer and ignoring the result has no effect so is ignored.

Comment: @gsamaras `-std=c11`, otherwise you didn't pick a standard, and it uses `gnu11` or sth.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason this compiles is because you are using the wrong GCC options - you are not compiling this with a strictly conforming C compiler but with GCC extensions.

Compiled properly with `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`, we get:

```
warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer|
error: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]|
warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer|
warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]|
```

`void` pointer de-referencing and arithmetic are gcc extensions. When such non-standard extensions are enabled, `void*` is treated as `uint8_t*` in terms of arithmetic, but you still can't de-reference it, because it is regarded as an incomplete type still.

As for what GCC does with this code in non-standard mode, with no optimizations enabled (Mingw/x86), nothing terribly exciting happens:

```
0x004014F0  push   %rbp
0x004014F1  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x004014F4  sub    $0x30,%rsp
0x004014F8  callq  0x402310 <__main>
0x004014FD  mov    $0x4,%ecx
0x00401502  callq  0x402b90 <malloc>
0x00401507  mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0040150B  mov    $0x0,%eax
0x00401510  add    $0x30,%rsp
0x00401514  pop    %rbp
0x00401515  retq
```

Comment: Check my updated question. Isn't that the command you are saying I should use? Maybe it's all Wandbox's fault?

Comment: @gsamaras The code in your screen shot is not the same as in the question. Use the same code and you should get the warnings/errors posted in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

in gcc, it's possible to perform pointer arithmetic on `void *` pointers ([How void pointer arithmetic is happening in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113301/how-void-pointer-arithmetic-is-happening-in-gcc))

And it's even possible to print `sizeof(void)` which is 1.

Your example issues a warning, but the line does nothing (like when you ignore a parameter by doing `(void)a` to avoid the "unused parameter" warning).

Try assigning something and gcc will complain

```
  void *c=malloc(4);
  *c = 'a';
```

gives me 1 warning, and 1 error

```
test.c:9:3: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
   *c = 'a';
   ^~
test.c:9:3: error: invalid use of void expression
   *c = 'a';
   ^
```

Or even use a `volatile char` cast on it:

```
test.c:9:3: error: invalid use of void expression
   (volatile char)*c;
```

So you can dereference it, but you cannot use the dereferenced value (also tried reading/assigning it, no way: you get "void value not ignored as it ought to be")

EDIT: semi-valid example (lifted from [memcpy: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125330/memcpy-warning-dereferencing-void-pointer))

```
  void *c=malloc(4);
  void *d=malloc(5);

  memcpy(d, &c[2], 2);
```

here you're dereferencing *with an offset* then you take the address again to get `c+2` : that works because of gcc pointer arithmetic. Of course:

```
memcpy(d, ((char*)c)+2, 2);
```

is the way to avoid the warning and is compliant to the standard.

Comment: It makes sense that this should be just optimized away if speaking of normal memory. But what if we define it as `volatile`?

Comment: I think that @EugeneSh. comment is the essence here, since I already knew that about the assignment (sorry, question updated). Because my code does nothing the actual derefencing does not happen? Or it does, and somehow the compiler is able to work this trough, even though it doesn't know the underlying type?

Comment: The question is: what is the point of the void pointer dereferencing? Abuse of the language? gcc allows arithmetic only for the convenience sake.

Comment: Moreover, what @EugeneSh. said may be reflected in my updated code, which invokes a "no effect" warning for `&c[0];`, but not for `*c;`.

Comment: you have the "right" to dereference it probably because it does nothing useful or harmful. Since I always remove warnings in my code, for me this is a clear error.

Comment: Can you have a volatile rvalue?

Comment: @gsamaras I have found a "useful" usage of dereferencing void*, see my edit

Comment: @gsamaras it does not actually dereference it. As I wrote it is only the pointer arithmetic assuming the byte size. IMO it is the abuse anyway. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbXZ6M3Y4UVlMSHM